# PHP ignores custom error handler

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

I want to create a custom error handler but PHP ignores it still uses the built in error handler. The example below gives a built in fatal error because test() is not defined:

```
 function critical_error($error_number,$error_string,$error_file,$error_line,$error_context) {
     echo "<strong>error:</strong> echo ".$error_string;
     exit();
 }

 set_error_handler("critical_error",8191);
 test();
 exit;
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably defining the error level wrong. Try using:

```
set_error_handler("critical_error", E_ALL);
```

Also notice that:

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined
>   function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING,
>   E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the
>   file where set_error_handler() is called.

But without your complete script (including `test()`) it's hard to tell. I've tested it on my local server and everything works fine.

Comment: Don't think he is, 8191 is everything from E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR and above. http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Comment: You're right about the notice part. _Fatal error: Call to undefined function_ is `E_ERROR` and user defined error handler won't be fired.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I think the issue was here that I did not add the E_ALL. test() is not defined, I wanted PHP to give me an fatal error to see if the custom error handler will catch it.